# Install K8s on Ubuntu - product_uuid or machine-id

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, multipass

Installing Kubernetes on Ubuntu I need the [product_uuid](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#verify-mac-address)

Butin my Ubuntu VM(Multipass) I get:

```
sudo cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
cat: /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid: No such file or directory
```

So I found [machine-id](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/machine-id.5.html):

```
cat /etc/machine-id
db4b9d9a3b194386b894dba21d7b3fb3
```

Is this a valid number for product_uuid when installing K8s or else, where is product_uuid?

Thanks

Comment: Those links are for using kubeadm. Do you need that vs using microk8s? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s#2-deploying-microk8s

Comment: Thanks, I am using kubeadm

Comment: I see. I believe Canonical's suggestion for running k8s in Multipaas is to use their own microk8s, though. Otherwise, you may want an alternative solution like Minikube to start its own VMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product_uuid` is main [board product UUID](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/ids.html)(set by the board manufacturer) and  may be used to identify a mainboard.

`machine-id` is a unique id specific to a linux installation.

```
ubuntu@k3s:~$ sudo dmidecode --type 1
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0100, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: QEMU
    Product Name: QEMU Virtual Machine
    Version: virt-6.2
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    UUID: Not Settable
```

Since multipass spins up a VM, product_uuid wont be available. k8s just needs a unique identifier, so machine-id should work.